# How to add upload utility to wmd editor?

Tags: upload, wmd

Has anyone succeeded to do this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are you trying to add a pre-built utility or are you trying to write your own one?

Comment: Does it matter in what version of WMD?

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by replacing Util.prompt with my own jquery.dialog method.  The prompt function takes a parameter as a callback, making it easy to create a drop-in replacement.

```
if (isImage) {
    // OLD: util.prompt(imageDialogText, imageDefaultText, makeLinkMarkdown);
    // WMD_IMAGE_GALLERY_URL loaded from a global settings elsewhere
    util.imageGallery(WMD_IMAGE_GALLERY_URL, makeLinkMarkdown);
}
else {
    util.prompt(linkDialogText, linkDefaultText, makeLinkMarkdown);
}
```

If you're interested, I wrote a [blog entry](http://urlencode.blogspot.com/2009/10/hacking-wmd-editor-into-using-custom.html) about it (with pictures!) which has some more sample code as well as some of the problems/solutions I encountered in implementing this.

Comment: I'd also be very interested in seeing the code for all of this as I need to implement an upload as per stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The following hack requires use of [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js), [jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js) and [Mike Alsup's jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js) for performing AJAX file uploads. The hack works with the linked versions (jQ 1.7.2 and jQUI 1.8.20). I can't guarantee compatibility with other versions.

---

In your `<head>`, you'll need to include the dependencies:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<link href='theme/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wmd/showdown.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wmd/wmd.js'></script>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='wmd/wmd.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.form.js'></script>
```

---

We actually need to make a single change to `wmd.js`.
Go on in there and search (ctrl+f) for `var form = doc.createElement("form");`
Immediately following this line, assign the form an id, **dialogform** will do: `form.id = "dialogform";`

---

Now on the front end, run:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wmd-image-button").live("click",function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".wmd-prompt-dialog").css({"opacity": "0", display: "none"});
        }, 100);
        var $div = $("<div>");
        var $form = $("<form>").attr({action: "submit_image.php", method: "post"})
        var $file = $("<input/>").attr({type: "file", name: "image"});
        var $name = $("<input/>").attr({type: "text", name: "name", placeholder: "Name"});
        var $submit = $("<input/>").attr("type", "submit");
        $form.append($name, $file, $submit).ajaxForm(function(r) {
            r = $.parseJSON(r);
            if(r.success){
                $("#dialogform input[type='text']").val(r.filename);
                $("#dialogform input[value='OK']").trigger("click");
                $div.dialog("close");
            }
        });
        $div.append($form).dialog({title: "Upload Image"});
    });
    $("#wmd-link-button").live("click", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".wmd-prompt-dialog").css("opacity", "1");
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

*Remember, the post was written for jQuery 1.7.2, and `live()` has since been deprecated. Please switch to `on()` if you're using a more recent version of jQuery*

---

And on the backend, in `submit_image.php`:

```
    $f = $_FILES['image'];
    $p = $_POST;
    $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
    $detectedType = exif_imagetype($f['tmp_name']);
    if(in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)){
        $pi = pathinfo($f['name']);
        $ext = $pi['extension'];
        $target = "img/" . strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $p['name'])) . "." . $ext;
        if(move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'], $target)){
            $returnArr = array(
                "success" => true,
                "filename" => site_url($target)
            );
            echo json_encode($returnArr);
        }
        else echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
    }
    else echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "msg" => "Invalid File Type."));
```

---

Hopefully that will get you started. This was written a couple of years ago, when my javascript skills were sub-par! Haha. I previously had this on a blog (which is now dead), with step-by-step instructions and explanations; lots of unnecessary fluff. Thanks [@Kamiccolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150918/kamiccolo) for bringing this link to my attention. I had to consult the way-back-machine in order to revive it.

Comment: Could You please, elaborate more, not just dropping an offsite link? having in mind, that site dead. At least at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to the control panel of WMD.
Search for the following string to find the place where buttons are being added:
`italicButton.XShift`
In [my version](http://moowmd.awardspace.info), the function is in class *SpritedButtonRow* and is called *build*.

Ignore the *setup* and *textOp* attributes. XShift is the position of the button image in the css sprite that comes with WMD, Instead of that, give the button a class and in the class specify the background image. Then Just add an *onclick* event to the button
that will do what you need it to do.
But, I don't think an upload button should be inside a text editor, does not make sense.